# Retrieve 1 value that links to all values from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I'm trying to display a list of all users in my database... each one with a link that will display their own information (in this case only displays user again and password), heres my code...

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','user','password')or die ('Connection Failed: '.mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('name')or die ('Error to select database '.mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY ID");



echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th>UserName</th>
</tr>";

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href="user.php?id='.$row['id'].'">' . $row['usuario'] . '</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I get the ID of each user through the URL to be a new variable in my user.php page to recognize each one...

```
    <?php 
      $numusu = $_GET['id']; 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=`$numusu`");
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo "<table><tr>";
      echo "<td>User:" . $row['usuario'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>Password:" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr></table>";
    }
     ?>
```

But for some reason I'm not able to display anything in user.php, I get the ID value and all just missing the information I just get an error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /site/test/test/test/login_php/user.php on line 15

What am I doing wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id='$numusu'`. Backticks only work for table and database names.

---

When you get `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`, it usually means `$result` is null and/or mysql_query failed. If you change the query to

```
$result = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
```

It should tell you that something like `Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'`.

Comment: Good catch! Putting numusu between `-brackets will indeed cause MySQL to interprete the word as a column name.